# Keep screen off while receiving notification and device is locked

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen, android-wake-lock

I googled a lot to manage notifications and I found that can be done using **Notification Listener** but I am stuck with the problem that is, I want to keep screen off (not event blinking of light) while receiving notification.

I used following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if ((notificationManager != null) && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);       
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_ENABLE_DO_NOT_DISTURB_SCREEN_FLASH);
    } else {
        if (b) {
            notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
        } else {
            notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
        }
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Don't have notification policy permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Can anyone give me idea to do this?

Your help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try keeping the importance level of the notification to minimum. It's a constant value in NotificationBuilder, it should stop the notifications from peeking and lighting up the lock screen

Comment: I want to do it for all the notification of all application, not only mine application.